# Google keyboard gestures not working for other languages than English (Moto G, Android 4.4.4)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, localization, swype, gboard

I can't get gestures ("swype") to work with Google Keyboard for languages other than English (which is my device language).

Gestures are activated in the keyboard settings, I have tried rebooting the phone, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Language and input -> Google Keyboard settings -> Add-on dictionaries. Scroll down/hit refresh to show all languages, then click the language you want to install, an "Install" button will appear, click it.

Gestures should now work for any language for which the dictionary is installed.

Comment: They actually don't.

Answer (score 0):

The best is still Google keyboard modified by Shaftamle that can be used for all Android versions. I made a personal dictionary large enough so that now it has 2 languages, bilingual, instant shortcuts... No other keyboard has this feature. See this link.. http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/tutorial-google-keyboard-indonesian-t3215118

Comment: Not sure about "*all Android versions*". Shaftamle mentioned this on their own thread: "*You must be on Android 4.0 or higher. It is a requirement of Google Keyboard.*"

Answer (score -1):

after reinstalling add on dictionaries swipe feature works.